# How to upgrade target API to 31 android

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to upload my aab file on playstore but am getting this message
[image]

How can I upgrade my API level to 31.

Part of my Gradle file

```
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "29.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 23
        compileSdkVersion = 30
        targetSdkVersion = 30
        ndkVersion = "20.1.5948944"
        glideVersion = "4.11.0"
        kotlin_version = "1.3.50"
        supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
        libre_build = !(isPlay.toBoolean())
        .............................
        ............................

    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The console is saying that your app is currently targeting API Level 30 instead of 31.

So, all you have to do is to change your `targetSdkVersion` from 30 to 31 and check if the app behavior hasn't changed.

On my side, I wrote this

```
android {
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.doe.john"
        minSdk 23
        targetSdk 31
        versionCode 15
        versionName "0.10.1"
        ...
    }
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `buildToolsVersion`

You can made like this:

```
ext {
        minSdkVersion = 23
        compileSdkVersion = 31
        targetSdkVersion = 31
        ndkVersion = "20.1.5948944"
        glideVersion = "4.11.0"
        kotlin_version = "1.3.50"
        supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
        libre_build = !(isPlay.toBoolean())
        .............................
        ............................

    }
```